# If I assign an int value to a variable which is inside an object of a class, then can I call it as boxing

Tags: boxing

In the Microsoft Docs the definition of boxing is:

> Boxing is used to store value types in the garbage-collected heap.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing#boxing

If I assign an int value to a variable which is inside an object of a class, then can I call it as boxing? In this case value type is storing from stack to heap.

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Student
    {
        public int Age;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var age = 10; // inside stack
            var s1 = new Student(); 
            s1.Age = age; // assign the value from stack to heap. is it boxing?
        }
    }
}
```

Or boxing is only happen when value type stored inside System.Object or any interface which is implemented by the value type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not boxing.

Everything in the heap has to be contained in an object. If you already have an object, as here, all is fine.

However, if you just want to put a value, by itself, in the heap, you don't have an object to place it in. That's when we "box" the value by constructing an object that just exists to contain that value.